# Ethers.js: ReferenceError: utils is not defined

Tags: javascript, filter, ethers.js

I'm trying to create a listener for incoming transactions with ethers.js (v5.6). According to the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/events/#events--filters), to listen to incoming transactions you need to create this filter:

```
// List all token transfers  *to*  myAddress:
filter = {
    address: tokenAddress,
    topics: [
        utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"),
        null,
        hexZeroPad(myAddress, 32)
    ]
};
```

Having this in my script gives me an error saying `utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"), ReferenceError: utils is not defined`. I can't find anything in the docs about importing an utils package. Can anyone sort me out?

My full code:

```
async function incomingTransactions() {
    if (loadedUser) {
        console.log("User loaded", loadedUser)
        let myAddress = loadedUser.publicKey
        let filter = {
            address: myAddress,
            topics: [
                utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"),
                null,
                hexZeroPad(myAddress, 32)
            ]
        };

        // let foo = await provider.getLogs(filter)
        // console.log(foo)
    } 
    console.log("No user loaded")
}

const interval = setInterval(function() {
    incomingTransactions();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Looks like it is on the global object and is a  [hash function](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#cryptographic-hash-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `utils` is part of the `ethers` object, and `hexZeroPad` and `id` are part of `utils` so you can use them like so:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers"); // assuming commonjs

ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(myAddress, 32);
```

Comment: ... and the docs keep omitting ethers. Thanks for this clarification.

Answer (score 5):

in version 6, utils doesn't exist as all the utils methods are now part of the ethers object, also dont forget there are some breaking changes, [check more on the migration page](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/#migrate-utils)

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers"); // assuming commonjs

//ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"); becomes 
ethers.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");

// ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(myAddress, 32); becomes 
ethers. zeroPadValue(myAddress, 32);
```

Comment: Every library seems to be focused on making as many updates as possible, voiding most tutorials out there!